# Multiline regex search with ag

Tags: regex, ag

I'd like to "AND" search text in spesific multiline range in a file by regex with ag(the_silver_searcher). But the regex pattern not work.

Following regex pattern works well.

`ag --multiline -G "^.*\.(md|txt)$" -C 1 -S "foo(\n|.)*baz" ./dev_note.md`

(output)

```
40-
41:foo
42:bar
43:baz
44-
```

But following regex pattern will output nothing.(no matched)

`ag --multiline -G "^.*\.(md|txt)$" -C 1 -S "(?=(.|\n)*(foo))(?=(.|\n)*(baz))" ./dev_note.md`

Also I tried: `ag --multiline -G "^.*\.(md|txt)$" -C 1 -S "(?=(.|\n)*(foo))(.|\n)*(?=(.|\n)*(baz))" ./dev_note.md`

Comment: Is there an example of the source file?

Comment: A full list of the `dev_note.md` file is here: https://gist.github.com/274273067e843aaaafb0659d6c27b4b5#file-dev_note-md-txt

Comment: So what results are you expecting with bottom two patterns? Just to be clear.